# ElasticBlockStore with StorageClass

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I can't connect EBS to SC.

Here is an error in PersistentVolumeClaim:

```
Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gp2": Failed to get AWS Cloud Provider. GetCloudProvider returned <nil> instead
```

Comment: I assume you aren't using EKS? If you deployed k8s yourself, are you sure you've set the `--cloud-provider` option? see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57718

Comment: kube-controller logs without cloud-config
`could not init cloud provider aws: error finding instance (id): error listing AWS instances: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain.`

kube-controller logs with cloud-config
 `Couldn't open cloud provider configuration /etc/kubernetes/aws-config.conf: &os.PathError{Op:"open", Path:"/etc/kubernetes/aws-config.conf", Err:0x2}`

Comment: I got same errors when renamed to cloud-config.

Comment: Now the problem in cloud-config, is someone have an example for aws?